# Books explaining differentiation under the integral sign

Tags: integration, reference-request, derivatives

I've heard that this is a great tool to have in you math toolkit, but I cannot comprehend this method just from the wiki entry and 2 page pdf files.

I'm looking for a book which has problems (preferably solutions). I'm not well versed in mathematical notation, but I'm currently doing a course on multi variable calculus. Is this method an alternative to the Jacobian, or am I mistaken? Is it really that useful?

Comment: [Link](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf).

Comment: @lucian I've seen this pdf before, but by looking at it it seems to me that this method can be used in very specific problems only. Then why is it called extremely useful?

Comment: It is only useful in very specific problems. But then again, so is a screwdriver. And I think screwdrivers are very useful.

Comment: @mixedmath I see what you did :). But isn't it a false analogy? Could I use successfully use differentiation under integral sign (hopefully reducing the amount of work) in solving integrals which can be expressed in "traditional" functions? Do you use this tool a lot?

Comment: There's no one-size-fits-all-tool-for-solving-all-integrals-out-there. **Not even complex integration!** *Some* integrals, for instance, are *so* hard, that they have to first be simplified with various different methods before *ultimately* being delivered into the hands of contour integration and/or the residue theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Calculus - FREDERICK S. WOODS

Calculus II - Tom M. Apostol

Advanced Calculus- ANGUS E. TAYLOR and W. ROBERT MANN